# Python Metaclass did not change the class when used

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming

I found this question while i searched the usage of metaclass in python.It's a good question with a wonderful answer,[See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python).But while i followed the example like this:

```
class UpperAttrMetaclass(type): 

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):

        attrs = ((name, value) for name, value in dct.items() if not name.startswith('__'))
        uppercase_attr = dict((name.upper(), value) for name, value in attrs)

        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, uppercase_attr)
class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__=UpperAttrMetaclass
    bar = 'bip'
```

Then:

```
print(hasattr(Foo,'bar'))
```

I was hoping it would output `False`,but instead it was `True`
It seems the metaclass didn't change anything at all.
I must have made a mistake.Glad if you can point it out to me!

EDIT:
I was using IDLE 3.2,to make my situation more clear.

EDIT:
Thanks for all the answers.And i found a good post on this.So i post it here[Metaclass in python 2&3](http://mikewatkins.ca/2008/11/29/python-2-and-3-metaclasses/#using-the-metaclass-in-python-3-x)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made no mistake. `print(hasattr(Foo,'bar'))` and `print dir(Foo)` give me:

```
False
['BAR', '__class__', ...
```

What's your Python version? Mine is 2.7.2

If you use Python 3.x, try removing the `__metaclass__` attribute and declaring your class as

```
class Foo(object, metaclass=UpperAttrMetaclass):
    ...
```

Comment: 3.2.2 but I also have 2.7 installed.Let me try it with that and see if that works

Comment: Works for me on both 2.7.2 (the original code) and on 3.2 (with `metaclass=`)

Comment: Ha,Interestingly it worked on 2.7 Something must have changed.

Comment: @NiklasB. Thanks.I see the problem now.

Answer (score 3):

As for @Irfy answer - in Python 3 the way to set a metaclass is to pass it as if it where a named-parameter in the class declaration - in your case, the code should be:

```
class UpperAttrMetaclass(type): 

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):

        attrs = ((name, value) for name, value in dct.items() if not name.startswith('__'))
        uppercase_attr = dict((name.upper(), value) for name, value in attrs)

        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, uppercase_attr)

class Foo(metaclass=UpperAttrMetaclass):
    bar = 'bip'
```

(In Python 3, there is no need to inherit from object as well)

Also, just use "dir" to check the class attributes, as in `dir(Foo)` . No need to be inspecting attribute by attribute with "hasattr" when you can see them all.

Comment: You mean when having a metaclass,you don't need to inherit from object?

Comment: In Python 3, all classes inherit from `object`, so there's no need to do so explicitly (there are no "old-style" classes).

Comment: As Kindall puts it - in Python 3, there is no need to inherit from object. But, yes, in Python 2, if you have a metaclass, you don't need to inherit from object either. (What inheriting from object actually does is setting your metaclass to `type`)